# Why is my code running infinitely?

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.5, infinite-loop

this is an even odd calculator that runs infinitely without any errors. Does anyone know how to fix this? Is it ok for me to call the method with the input from times?

```
def calc(time):
    i = 1
    while i <= time:
       num = int(input("Enter your number"))
       i + 1
       x=0
       y=0

       if (int(num) % 2 == 0):
          even = True
          print("even")


       elif (int(num) % 2 != 0):
          odd = True
          print("odd")



       if (odd == True):
         x += 1

       elif (even == True):
         y += 1


times = int(input("How many numbers will you be putting in this calc?"))

calc(times)
```

Comment: Can you please make sure the indentation is correct? while loop and the variables? Its python after all :p

Comment: `i + 1` does nothing. `i += 1` increments

Comment: Ya i am using python3 . It seems to be working fine(no errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a formatting issue with stackoverflow and not a formatting issue with your actual code.  The lines after your while loop need to be indented which I'm assuming you are doing.  The problem you have is that you aren't incrementing i.  The first line after your input you have i + 1.  That does nothing as you aren't assigning it to anything.  You have x += 1 and y += 1 later on in your code which increments and assigns.  So basically change your i+1 line to be i += 1 or i = i + 1

Comment: There's other issues here. Also, instead of assuming, you should be posting a comment.

Comment: Yes, the indentation is correct on my own code. Thank you for that answer. I cant believe i missed that!

Answer (score 2):

Just a few things you have wrong, the rest are pretty good, explain are in the comments:

All the variables in [x, y , even , odd] are useless at all, so that's why I erased them.

```
def calc(time):
    i = 1
    while i <= time:
      num = int(input("Enter your number"))
      i+=1 # important thing here, to update the value the symbol is +=, not just +

      if (int(num) % 2 == 0):
          print("even")

      else: # there is no need of elif, if the number is not even, by definition, it is odd
          print("odd")

times = int(input("How many numbers will you be putting in this calc?"))

calc(times)
```

you can try it here, and see how do correctly the job :) -> https://repl.it/Nm70/0

Comment: I think he/she also wants to keep track of how many even or odd numbers the user inputs, that's why the x and y variables, but he/she is restarting them each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Line number 5 should be i = i+1

Comment: I think that was all the problem about... My answer was to much haha

Answer (score -2):

Everything that you want in the while loop needs to be indented by one "tab" like so:

```
while i <= time:
    #Code goes here
```

Comment: This is not the only issue here.

Comment: Well it is the issue that's causing OP's code to run indefinitely.

Comment: No, it isn't. If he didn't indent it it would be an IndentationError.

Comment: Neither `i` nor `time` change in the loop and there is no other exit condition.